# Failed to created container because unknown shorthand

Tags: docker

I'm new in docker and git
Here's what I have done

1. login to deployment environment (in this case EC2) using git bash
2. clone previous version or both frontend and backend
3. installing docker

My issue

when i try to build container using this code
`docker build -t your-image-name`

it shows unknown shorthand `-t`

Comment: Ensure that you have latest docker version installed. And `docker build -t <your-image-name> .`, check you didn't missed the `.` at the end, as it specifies the build context.